# PHP MySQL search with multiple criteria

Tags: php, mysql, search, database-table

I have a search form in a website and would like to have several search terms which is input by the user to perform db search, terms as below:

- Keywords
- Property For (Sale, Rent...)
- Property Type (Apartment, Terrace House...)
- State
- Min Price
- Max Price

Here is script to perform search with above term's input

```
public function get_property_list_by_search($start, $per_page, $keyword, $prop_for, $min, $state, $ptype, $max, $mysqli)
{
    if(empty($start) && empty($per_page))
    {
        return 0;
    }

    $start = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $mysqli->real_escape_string($start));
    $per_page = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $mysqli->real_escape_string($per_page));
    $keyword = $mysqli->real_escape_string(stripslashes($keyword));
    $prop_for = $mysqli->real_escape_string(stripslashes($prop_for));
    $state = $mysqli->real_escape_string(stripslashes($state));
    $ptype = $mysqli->real_escape_string(stripslashes($ptype));
    $min_price = self::num_clean($mysqli->real_escape_string($min));
    $max_price = self::num_clean($mysqli->real_escape_string($max));

    $t1 = '';
    $t2 = '';
    $t3 = '';
    $t4 = '';
    $t5 = '';

    if(isset($keyword) && !empty($keyword)){
        $t1 = " AND `proj_title` LIKE '%".$keyword."%' OR `proj_addr` LIKE '%".$keyword."%' OR `proj_area` LIKE '%".$keyword."%'";
    }
    if(isset($prop_for) && !empty($prop_for)){
        $t2 = " AND `proj_for`='".$prop_for."'";
    }
    if(isset($state) && !empty($state)){
        $t3 = " AND `state`='".$state."'";
    }
    if(isset($ptype) && !empty($ptype)){
        $t4 = " AND `proj_cat`='".$ptype."'";
    }
    //min & max
    if((isset($min_price) && !empty($min_price)) && (isset($max_price) && !empty($max_price))){
        $t5 = " AND `price` BETWEEN '".$min_price."' AND '".$max_price."'";
    }
    //min only
    if(!empty($min_price) && empty($max_price)){
        $t5 = " AND `price` >= '".$min_price."'";
    }
    //max only
    if(empty($min_price) && !empty($max_price)){
        $t5 = " AND `price` <= '".$max_price."'";
    }

    $sql = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `project` WHERE `status`='1' ".
    $t1." ".$t2." ".$t3." ".$t4." ".$t5." ".
    "ORDER BY `posted_date` DESC LIMIT ".$start.", ".$per_page);

    if($sql->num_rows > 0){
        return $sql;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

The query output will something like:

```
SELECT * FROM `project` 
WHERE `proj_title` LIKE '%keywords%' 
OR `proj_addr` LIKE '%keywords%' 
OR `proj_area` LIKE '%keywords%' 
AND `proj_for`='Sale' AND `state`='Somewhere' AND `proj_cat`='8' AND `price` BETWEEN '250000' AND '600000'
```

(Datatype for `price` is `DECIMAL(10,2)`, it stored value like `250000.00`)

However, the returned results is not like expected (not accurate), its also will come out a result with price more than 600000 and project category which is out of '8' which is not fancy for the end user to searching in the website.

is there any way to refine on the query to perform more specific?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of taking these variables you should use  ".=" operator.

```
/*      $t1 = '';
        $t2 = '';
        $t3 = '';
        $t4 = '';
        $t5 = '';
*/
        $q = "SELECT * FROM `property` WHERE `status`='1' ";

// You need to enclose all **OR** logical tests in parenthesis.
// Moreover most of the usages of isset function are useless,
// as your are initializing many variables

        if($keyword && !empty($keyword)){
            $q .= " AND (`p_title` LIKE '%".$keyword."%' OR `address` LIKE '%".$keyword."%' OR `area` LIKE '%".$keyword."%')";
        }
        if($prop_for && !empty($prop_for)){
// If you are using double quotes you really don't need  handle to concatenation.
        $q .= " AND `p_for`='$prop_for'";
        }
        if($state && !empty($state)){
            $q .= " AND `state`='$state'";
        }
        if($ptype && !empty($ptype)){
            $q .= " AND `p_category`='$ptype'";
        }
        //min only
        if($min_price && !empty($min_price)){
            $q .= " AND `price` >= '".$min_price."'";
        }
        //max only
        if($max_price && !empty($max_price)){
            $q .= " AND `price` <= '$max_price'";
        }

// When you are not using OFFSET keyword,
//the first number after LIMIT keyword should be the number of records
                $q .= " ORDER BY `posted_date` DESC LIMIT $per_page , $start;";
                $sql = $mysqli->query($q);
```

Comment: thanks man. Can I learn from you? how can I output a query for checking purpose from a class? I still not know what's goes wrong with the query causing failure.

Comment: Oh sure @conmen, :) you can add me on FB(fb.com/gahse). I am just asking you to add
   echo $q;
before this line
  $sql = $mysqli->query($q);

This will return the query string then you can copy this string and paste it to any MySql client like phpmyadmin or sqlyog. It will help you to remove all syntax errors.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to need parentheses.

```
SELECT * FROM `project` WHERE (`proj_title` LIKE '%keywords%' OR `proj_addr` LIKE '%keywords%' OR `proj_area` LIKE '%keywords%') AND `proj_for`='Sale' AND `state`='Somewhere' AND `proj_cat`='8' AND `price` BETWEEN '250000' AND '600000'
```

Without the parentheses it just has to match one of the criteria before the last OR.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_SESSION['login']))
{
 echo "<div align=\"right\"><strong><a href=\"index.php\"> Home </a>|
 <a href=\"signout.php\">Signout</a>|
 <a href=\"home.php\">Profile</a></strong></div>";


 }
 else
 {
    echo "&nbsp;";
 }

$con=  mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
  $d=mysql_select_db("matrimonial",$con);
   $gender=$_POST['gender'];
  $age1=$_POST['age1'];
  $age2=$_POST['age2'];
  $city=$_POST['city'];
  $subcast=$_POST['subcast'];
  $result=mysql_query("select * from matri where gender='$gender' and age between '$age1' and '$age2' and city='$city' and subcast='$subcast'");

if($gender && !empty($gender))
{
 $result .= " AND `gender`='$gender'";
}

if($age1 && !empty($age1)){
        $result .= " AND `age`='$age1'";
    }   
 if($age2 && !empty($age2)){
       $result .= " AND `age`='$age2'";
    }  

 if($city && !empty($city)){
       $result .= " AND `city`='$city'";
    }  

  if($subcast && !empty($subcast)){
       $result .= " AND `subcast`='$subcast'";
    }  

   $result .= " select * from ";

   $sql = $mysql->query($result);
how to run this code
```

Comment: i want to search this field with select or without select by user.if dont select than pring all othere wise by search condition, what i do

Answer (score 0):

On the price difference you should do a if the price if between the 2 values else only 1 value.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).